# How to Use Loopback Datasource Connector as Knex.js Connection

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, knex.js

We're using the Knex.js SQL Query Builder with Loopback to query the database. Both Knex and Loopback have their own datasource connection pool and we would like to use the Loopback connection for both Knex and Loopback. Knex does provide a function to provide an external connection: [see](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-connection). However, we're getting errors when using the Loopback connector with Knex. Here's the code:

```
// Init Knex.
let knex = require('knex')({ client: 'mysql');

// Get the Loopback connector
let ds = this.dataSource.connector;
...
return knex(table.name)
   .connection(ds)
   .transacting(trx)
   .update(row)
   .where('rowid', row.rowid)
```

Here's the error:

Unhandled rejection Error: There is no pool defined on the current client
    at assign.acquireConnection (c:\Projects\27\server\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:202:25)

Comment: This looks like a knex error, which version of knex do you have? I recall there was a version (which 0.8.5 fixed) that would error out with this message.

Comment: We're using 0.9.0. I'm thinking that the Loopback connection and Knex connection are just not compatible.